# input element, type of "text", has no text in label

Tags: html

```
<input aria-labelledby="searchLabel" type="text" name="s" id="s" value="" placeholder="Search" />
```

also i got an other issue here on this line " input element, type of "text", missing an associated label". What i need to fix?

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/input.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

The `aria-labelledby` attribute expects an element's ID for the element to be used as the label. So in your case, you need to have an element like

```html
<div id="searchLabel">Label Text Here</div>
```

to be the label for your text input. That is where you will write the text for the label, and that will be the label "associated" with the text input.
Here's the related page on the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute) if you want to read more on the topic :)

Comment: <div id="searchLabel">Label Text Here</div>
        <input aria-labelledby="searchLabel" type="text" name="s" 

still nothing. i am doing something wrong?